# Trouble with Accordion and toggling icons

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

I am trying this for hours, but seems I have somehow a total brain-fart
What I want to achieve is making an accordion with toggling icons and sliding up panels. 
This basically works the minus changes to plus but not when I toggle click the certain header.

```
$('.accordion-wrapper').on('click', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();

    $(this).next('div.accordion-panel').stop(true, false, true).slideToggle();
    // $(this).find('.unalex-plus').toggleClass('glyphicon-plus glyphicon-minus');
    $('div.accordion-panel').not($(this).next('div.accordion-panel')).slideUp();

    if (!$(this).hasClass('active-panel')) {
        $('.accordion-wrapper').find('.unalex-plus').removeClass('glyphicon-minus').addClass('glyphicon-plus');
        $(this).find('.unalex-plus').removeClass('glyphicon-plus').addClass('glyphicon-minus ');
        $(this).addClass("active-panel");
    } else {
        $('this').find('.unalex-plus').removeClass('glyphicon-minus').addClass('glyphicon-plus');
        $('.accordion-wrapper').find('.unalex-plus').removeClass('glyphicon-plus').addClass('glyphicon-plus');
        $(this).removeClass('active-panel');
    }
});
```

This is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/emd381md/11/

Answer (score 3):

Here is a working demo https://jsfiddle.net/ju9L9rne/13/.

Issues were with the names of classes in the if statement. You were using `.unalex-plus` which is a class all the accordians have, which is what caused the problems.

So I just changed that class to either `.glyphicon-minus` or `.glyphicon-plus` depending on, which was needed.

The changed code:

```
  if (!$(this).hasClass('active-panel')) {
    $('.accordion-wrapper').find('.glyphicon-minus').removeClass('glyphicon-minus').addClass('glyphicon-plus');
    $(this).find('.glyphicon-plus').removeClass('glyphicon-plus').addClass('glyphicon-minus ');
    $(this).addClass("active-panel");
  } else {
    $('.accordion-wrapper').find('.glyphicon-minus').removeClass('glyphicon-minus').addClass('glyphicon-plus');
    $(this).find('.glyphicon-plus').removeClass('glyphicon-plus').addClass('glyphicon-minus');
    $(this).removeClass('active-panel');
  }
```

Comment: Thanks but this just partly solves the problem, I can toggle them fine now in your fiddle but the non active ones are not jumping back to plus but staying at minus :(

Comment: updated the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ju9L9rne/4/ I had put the worng class name in one of the class changers  **Edit**: nevermind still and issue with first accordian keeping the minus

Answer (score 3):

I've edited your [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/emd381md/17/).

You shouldn't use `addClass` and `removeClass` in that manner.
[toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) is a better (and more readable) solution.

Comment: omg thanks that's solved it :D <3 I really feel like having suffered from a brainfart now lol.

Answer (score 1):

I don't check your whole code but this looks a bit crazy, maybe the error is here?

```
$('.accordion-wrapper').find('.unalex-plus').removeClass('glyphicon-plus').addClass('glyphicon-plus');
```

You first remove glyphicon-plus and add it afterwards.